# Why Am I getting hmr invalidate could not fast refresh error in vite react i tried setting it to false but nothing is working

Tags: reactjs, vite

```
import React from "react";
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import data from "../assets/explore.json";
import monthly from "../assets/montly.json";
const games = () => {
  let handle = useParams();
  const func1 = monthly.map((game) => {
    if (game["id"] == handle.name) {
      return (
        <div key={game["id"]}>
          <h2>{game["name"]}</h2>
          <img src={game["image"]} alt="" />
          <p>{game["About Game"]}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });
const func2 = data.map((game) => {
    if (game["id"] == handle.name) {
      return (
        <div key={game["id"]}>
          <h2>{game["name"]}</h2>
          <img src={game["image"]} alt="" />
          <p>{game["About Game"]}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });
  return <>{func1 || func2}</>;
};

export default games;
```

`hmr invalidate /src/components/game.jsx Could not Fast Refresh. Learn more at https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/tree/main/packages/plugin-react#consistent-components-exports`

```
hmr invalidate /src/components/game.jsx
 Could not Fast Refresh. Learn more at https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/tree/main/packages/plugin-react#consistent-components-exports
```

I tried turning it off but it didn't work when i remove func1 and func2 component and render a simple div element it works fine but not with these function components

Answer (score 1):

This is because the exported `games` is not in CamelCase. See [this github comment](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/4583#discussioncomment-5602691) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem how to solve it

**hmr invalidate /src/hooks/usePatientContext.jsx Could not Fast Refresh. Learn more at https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/tree/main/packages/plugin-react#consistent-components-exports**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const ModalFormContext = createContext();

export const ModalFormProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    fullname: "",
    birthday: "",
    hospitalNumber: "",
    religion: "",
    address: "",
    dateOfAdmission: "",
    complaint: "",
    diagnosis: "",
    addedBy: "",
    patientPicture: "",
  });

  return (
    <ModalFormContext.Provider value={{ formData, setFormData }}>
      {children}
    </ModalFormContext.Provider>
  );
};
```